# How'd I catch exceptions for the below trigger?

Tags: postgresql, exception, psql

I have the below function that returns a trigger, however it may fail sometimes and when it does the trigger will stop all data from being inserted into the database. So, I wanted to catch the exception however, it doesn't work.

How is it possible to catch an exception in postgres.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
'BEGIN
UPDATE
    "EVENT"
SET
    rules = (
                            SELECT
                                string_agg(DISTINCT st ->> ''id'', '', '') AS rules
                            FROM
                                "JSON_STORAGE" aes,
                                jsonb_array_elements("EVENT_DATA" -> ''fields'' #> ''{Tracking}'') AS st
                            WHERE
                                (st ->> ''id'' LIKE ''rule_%'') AND
                                aes."EVENT_ID" = NEW."EVENT_ID")
WHERE
    NEW."EVENT_ID" = "EVENT"."EVENT_ID";


UPDATE
  "EVENT"
 SET
 longitude =
                SELECT
                  (CASE
                    WHEN (trim(both ''" '' FROM replace(regexp_replace( "EVENT_DATA"-> ''fields'' -> ''custom_fields'' ->> ''device_data'', ''[\\]{2,}"([^,:])'', ''\1'', ''g''), ''\"'', ''"''))::json -> ''objects'' -> 0 -> ''data'' -> ''device_info_logs'' -> 0 ->> ''device_type'' = ''Android'') THEN
                        trim(both ''"'' FROM replace(regexp_replace("EVENT_DATA"-> ''fields'' -> ''custom_fields'' ->> ''inauth_device_data'', ''[\\]{2,}"([^,:])'', ''\1'', ''g''), ''\"'', ''"''))::json -> ''objects'' -> 0 -> ''data'' -> ''gps_location_logs'' -> 0 ->> ''location_wifi_longitude''
                    else
                        trim(both ''"'' FROM replace(regexp_replace("EVENT_DATA"-> ''fields'' -> ''custom_fields'' ->> ''inauth_device_data'', ''[\\]{2,}"([^,:])'', ''\1'', ''g''), ''\"'', ''"''))::json -> ''objects'' -> 0 -> ''data'' -> ''gps_location_logs'' -> 0 ->> ''longitude''
                   END),
  latitude =
                SELECT
                  (CASE
                    WHEN (trim(both ''" '' FROM replace(regexp_replace( "EVENT_DATA"-> ''fields'' -> ''custom_fields'' ->> ''inauth_device_data'', ''[\\]{2,}"([^,:])'', ''\1'', ''g''), ''\"'', ''"''))::json -> ''objects'' -> 0 -> ''data'' -> ''device_info_logs'' -> 0 ->> ''device_type'' = ''Android'') THEN
                        trim(both ''"'' FROM replace(regexp_replace("EVENT_DATA"-> ''fields'' -> ''custom_fields'' ->> ''inauth_device_data'', ''[\\]{2,}"([^,:])'', ''\1'', ''g''), ''\"'', ''"''))::json -> ''objects'' -> 0 -> ''data'' -> ''gps_location_logs'' -> 0 ->> ''location_wifi_latitude''
                    else
                        trim(both ''"'' FROM replace(regexp_replace("EVENT_DATA"-> ''fields'' -> ''custom_fields'' ->> ''inauth_device_data'', ''[\\]{2,}"([^,:])'', ''\1'', ''g''), ''\"'', ''"''))::json -> ''objects'' -> 0 -> ''data'' -> ''gps_location_logs'' -> 0 ->> ''latitude''
                   END)
                FROM
                  "JSON_STORAGE" aes
                WHERE
                  aes."EVENT_ID" = NEW."EVENT_ID" AND
                  aes."EVENT_DATA"-> ''fields'' -> ''custom_fields'' ->> ''device_data'' LIKE ''%{%:%}%'' and
                  aes."EVENT_DATA"->''fields''->>''event_type''=''transaction_submission''
  WHERE
      NEW."EVENT_ID" = "EVENT"."EVENT_ID" AND
   "EVENT".ip_geo_longitude IS NULL AND
   "EVENT".ip_geo_latitude IS NULL;

exception when others then
raise notice ''The transaction is in an uncommittable state. ''
             ''Transaction was rolled back'';
RETURN
    NEW;
END'
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your trigger...

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure at all what you actually want to do with your trigger (some explanation woud help). The way you wrote it, it has several syntax errors.

*Maybe* this is more what you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        UPDATE
            "EVENT"
        SET
            rules = (SELECT
                         string_agg(DISTINCT st ->> 'id', ', ') AS rules
                     FROM
                         "JSON_STORAGE" aes,
                         /* This doesn't make much sense to me... */
                         jsonb_array_elements("EVENT_DATA" -> 'fields' #> '{Tracking}') AS st
                     WHERE
                        (st ->> 'id' LIKE 'rule_%') 
                        AND aes."EVENT_ID" = NEW."EVENT_ID"
                     )
        WHERE
            "EVENT"."EVENT_ID" = NEW."EVENT_ID" ;

        /* Maybe you just want to do this:
        NEW.rules = (SELECT
                         string_agg(DISTINCT st ->> 'id', ', ') AS rules
                     FROM
                         "JSON_STORAGE" aes,
                         jsonb_array_elements("EVENT_DATA" -> 'fields' #> '{Tracking}') AS st
                     WHERE
                        (st ->> 'id' LIKE 'rule_%') 
                        AND aes."EVENT_ID" = NEW."EVENT_ID"
                     ) ;
        */              

        UPDATE
            "EVENT"
        SET
            longitude /* ip_geo_longitude ?? */ =
                (CASE
                     WHEN (trim(both '" ' FROM replace(regexp_replace( "EVENT_DATA"-> 'fields' -> 'custom_fields' ->> 'device_data', '[\\]{2,}"([^,:])', '\1', 'g'), '\"', '"'))::json -> 'objects' -> 0 -> 'data' -> 'device_info_logs' -> 0 ->> 'device_type' = 'Android') THEN
                        trim(both '"' FROM replace(regexp_replace("EVENT_DATA"-> 'fields' -> 'custom_fields' ->> 'inauth_device_data', '[\\]{2,}"([^,:])', '\1', 'g'), '\"', '"'))::json -> 'objects' -> 0 -> 'data' -> 'gps_location_logs' -> 0 ->> 'location_wifi_longitude'
                     ELSE
                         trim(both '"' FROM replace(regexp_replace("EVENT_DATA"-> 'fields' -> 'custom_fields' ->> 'inauth_device_data', '[\\]{2,}"([^,:])', '\1', 'g'), '\"', '"'))::json -> 'objects' -> 0 -> 'data' -> 'gps_location_logs' -> 0 ->> 'longitude'
                END),
            latitude /* ip_geo_latitude ?? */ =
                (CASE
                     WHEN (trim(both '" ' FROM replace(regexp_replace( "EVENT_DATA"-> 'fields' -> 'custom_fields' ->> 'inauth_device_data', '[\\]{2,}"([^,:])', '\1', 'g'), '\"', '"'))::json -> 'objects' -> 0 -> 'data' -> 'device_info_logs' -> 0 ->> 'device_type' = 'Android') THEN
                         trim(both '"' FROM replace(regexp_replace("EVENT_DATA"-> 'fields' -> 'custom_fields' ->> 'inauth_device_data', '[\\]{2,}"([^,:])', '\1', 'g'), '\"', '"'))::json -> 'objects' -> 0 -> 'data' -> 'gps_location_logs' -> 0 ->> 'location_wifi_latitude'
                     ELSE
                         trim(both '"' FROM replace(regexp_replace("EVENT_DATA"-> 'fields' -> 'custom_fields' ->> 'inauth_device_data', '[\\]{2,}"([^,:])', '\1', 'g'), '\"', '"'))::json -> 'objects' -> 0 -> 'data' -> 'gps_location_logs' -> 0 ->> 'latitude'
                END)
        FROM
            "JSON_STORAGE" aes
        WHERE
                "EVENT"."EVENT_ID" = NEW."EVENT_ID"
            AND "EVENT".ip_geo_longitude IS NULL 
            AND "EVENT".ip_geo_latitude IS NULL
            AND aes."EVENT_ID" = NEW."EVENT_ID" 
            AND aes."EVENT_DATA"-> 'fields' -> 'custom_fields' ->> 'device_data' LIKE '%{%:%}%' 
            AND aes."EVENT_DATA"->'fields'->>'event_type' = 'transaction_submission' ;

   EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. '
             'Transaction was rolled back';
   END ;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

This version *does compile*. Check it *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e7ef0d51fc6513002e469c9ee55c4fde)*. Whether it does what you desire... is another story.

Comment: It will compile, but sometimes the second and third update statements cannot parse the data and they throw an error. In those cases, I want the trigger to fail gracefully instead of throwing an error and not letting the entities to persist on the database.